# Claim sunSBR staking rewards

Tags: solana-program, transactions, wallet, transfer, sendtransactionerror

Claim sunSBR staking rewards
×
failed to send transaction: Transaction simulation failed: Error processing Instruction 0: custom program error: 0x1772

how can i solve this problem ?